# IntelliJ Alt-Click to drag

Tags: intellij-idea

Some time ago in a code-haze I rant across some 'Alt-Click to drag' option somewhere in IntelliJ. I turned the option ON to test it. Now I realize that decades of regular Click-drag are not so simple to unlearn and I want to turn it off again, except I cannot locate that option again.

How to turn off the Alt-Click to drag option in IntelliJ?

Comment: If you go to `Find Action` and search for `Drag-and-drop`, do you get a result, describing your case, which you can turn off/on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `UI: drag-and-drop with Alt press only`, which can be found through `Help > Find Action` and the searching for `UI: drag` where ti should pop-up immediately.

[image: drag-drop]

You can turn it off through this interface easily.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!!

Comment: Glad to help :)